# unhandle promise rejection warning. even though i added catch statement after then

Tags: node.js, mongoose, es6-promise

I got an unhandle promise rejection warning when I'm saving to mondodb (with mongoose), but i implemented the catch statement.
So I don't get why I have this warning.

Bellow my code,
cheers.

--declaring the function with promise :

```
module.exports = {

getGameResult : () => {
    var gameResult = new GameResultModel();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

        GameResultModel.find({}, function (err, docs){

            if (err) reject(err);
            if (!err) resolve(docs);

        });
    })

}
```

}

--calling the function :

```
 router.get("/all", (req, res) => {

databaseFunction.getGameResult()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.send(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
```

});

Comment: Your `catch()` is probably throwing, because you can't send a response after the headers have already been sent.

Comment: Not the question, but you don't need to create your own promise here. You can replace that whole method with `GameResultModel.find({}).exec()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
GameResultModel.find({}, function (err, docs){
    if (err) reject(err);
    if (!err) resolve(docs);
}).catch(err => console.error("db.find has some error ", err));
```

I recently had a similar issue and if this solution helps I would need to find for you the source where I found a good description of the issue and the resolution.